# Rails undefined method in datables.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the Railscast on remote data for DataTables.  To make it work, you create a datatable.rb

I'm trying to define a select that is used in 3 places in the datatable.rb

This is the code:

```
class Workorders3Datatable

delegate :params, :h, :link_to, :number_to_currency, to: :@view

def initialize(view)
  @view = view
end

def mygroupsopenwos(user)
  select("workorders.*").joins("left outer join empgroups ON empgroups.workgroup_id=workorders.workgroup_id").where("empgroups.employee_id = ?", user).where("wostatus_id NOT IN (?)", [231, 230, 9263, 9264, 232] )
end

def as_json(options = {})
  {
      sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
      iTotalRecords: workorders.mygroupsopenwos(current_user).count,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: workorders.mygroupsopenwos(current_user).total_entries,,
      aaData: data
  }
end

private

def data
  workorders.mygroupsopenwos(current_user).map do |workorder|
    [
...
```

But, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `mygroupsopenwos' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f9b046ccb08>:
```

How do I define `mygroupsopenwos` so I can use it?  Should I put it in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `workorders.` before `workorders.mygroupsopenwos(current_user)`

`mygroupsopenwos` is an instance method declared a few lines up!

Comment: Thanks - I also added changed the line `select("workorders.*")` to `workorders.select("workorders.*")`